# AppleScript: Importing selected directories into albums in Photos

Tags: applescript

I am trying to create a script for importing directories as albums in Yosemite's Photos.

```
activate application "SystemUIServer"
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    repeat with flder in (get selection as alias list)
        set albumName to name of flder
        tell application "Photos"
            make new album named albumName

            set imageList to {}
            repeat with i from 1 to number of items in flder
                set this_item to item i of flder as alias
                set the end of imageList to this_item
            end repeat

            import imageList into album albumName
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

According to what I've found, this should work – it doesn't:

```
error "Photos got an error: 
     Can’t make alias \"Macintosh HD:Users:knyttl:Pictures:archive:2014:01_prom:\" into type specifier." number -1700 
     from alias "Macintosh HD:Users:knyttl:Pictures:archive:2014:01_prom:" to specifier
```

It compains on `number` in the `repeat` section. I am not even sure whether the syntax is correct – on some places I saw `number` on some other `count`, on some other places the iteration over files was done in completely different manner. I will be happy for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed, it seems to be an issue with separating Photos and Finder `tell` blocks.

Here's what I got to work, tested with multiple folders at a time:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    repeat with flder in (get selection)
        set albumName to name of flder
        set imageList to {}
        repeat with i from 1 to (count of items of flder)
            set photo to item i of flder
            set the end of imageList to photo as alias
        end repeat

        tell application "Photos"
            set newAlbum to make new album named albumName
            import imageList into newAlbum
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is a terminology clash in the `Photos` tell block while gathering the items of the folder which is actually `Finder` terminology.

try this, I separated the application tell blocks to warp only the specific terminology, respectively.

```
activate application "SystemUIServer"
tell application "Finder" to set folderList to selection
repeat with aFolder in folderList
    set albumName to name of aFolder
    tell application "Photos" to set newAlbum to make new album named albumName
    set imageList to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in aFolder
        set this_item to item i of aFolder as alias
        set the end of imageList to this_item
    end repeat
    tell application "Photos" to import imageList into newAlbum
end repeat
```

or easier

```
activate application "SystemUIServer"
tell application "Finder" to set folderList to selection
repeat with aFolder in folderList
    tell application "Finder"
        set albumName to name of aFolder
        set imageList to files of aFolder as alias list
    end tell
    tell application "Photos"
        set newAlbum to make new album named albumName
        import imageList into newAlbum
    end tell
end repeat
```